# Redirect URL to latest post in RSS feed

Tags: php, redirect, rss

I am trying to create a page (`example.com/latest`) that redirects to my most recent newsletter.

So far I have successfully loaded the RSS feed and created a variable for the URL of the latest newsletter. The problem is redirecting to it without the URL changing. Using `require` or `include` gives me this error:

> Warning: require(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server
> configuration by allow_url_include=0 in xxx

Here's my code with `require` left in:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://example.com/feed');
$url = $xml->channel->item[0]->link;

require($url); // this gives the error above
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using `file_get_contents` instead of `require`, so my code is:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://example.com/feed');
$url = $xml->channel->item[0]->link;

file_get_contents($url);
```